# Convert string to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, resultset

I got a result set in array format and i want to make square bracket value as a key and the other one as a value

here is my code

```
[Name]asdasdasd [Email]dfgdfg@in.com [Phone Number]42342342342 [Subject]dsafsdfsd [Company Name]ZXZXZX [Country]Antarctica
```

i want  output like :- `array("name"=>"asdasdasd", "Email"=>"dfgdfg@in.com");`

how can i do this in PHP any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks Jassi

Comment: i want to convert string to array with the following output, can you tell me how can it possible

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  What have you tried so far?  We aren't going to code for you.

Comment: @jassi9911 try `preg_match_all()`

Comment: i tried using explode function but didn't get the exact output what i want it.

Comment: where do you get such a string from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
<?php
$str = '[Name]asdasdasd [Email]dfgdfg@in.com [Phone Number]42342342342 [Subject]dsafsdfsd [Company Name]ZXZXZX [Country]Antarctica ';

preg_match_all('#\[([^\]]+)\]\s*([^\]\[]*[^\]\[\s])#msi', $str, $matches);

$keys = $matches[1];
$values = $matches[2];

// PHP 5
var_dump( array_combine($keys, $values) );
?>

array(6) {
  ["Name"]=>
  string(9) "asdasdasd"
  ["Email"]=>
  string(13) "dfgdfg@in.com"
  ["Phone Number"]=>
  string(11) "42342342342"
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(9) "dsafsdfsd"
  ["Company Name"]=>
  string(6) "ZXZXZX"
  ["Country"]=>
  string(10) "Antarctica"
}
```

The regex is a bit more complicated looking, but it basically matches anything but [], allows whitespace in the value and makes sure that the last character isn't [] or whitespace. You could probably get away with `([^\]\[\s]+)` if you knew you were never going to have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt this code below for your exact formatting (from [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)):

```
<?php

$assoc_array = array("Key1" => "Value1", "Key2" => "Value2");

$new_array = array_map(create_function('$key, $value', 'return $key.":".$value." # ";'), array_keys($assoc_array), array_values($assoc_array));

print implode($new_array);

?>
```

Which will output:

```
Key1:Value1 # Key2:Value2 #
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in someone giving you the exact code, this can be done with some basic functions. Read up on some of the following functions and work something out for yourself, learn ;)

- [`explode()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [`strpos()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [`substr()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Or if you're feeling adventurous, there's always: [`preg_match_all()`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).